# ListView using custom BaseAdapter- works fine but not for the first item added

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I'm new in Android and I'm having troubles with adding items to `ListView` using custom class extending `BaseAdapter`..

So, I have a `MainActivity` with a menu, that allow to chose `Add List Item`. It starts new activity named `InputDataActivity`:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,InputDataActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i,1);

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

`InputDataActivity` contains of two `EditText's` allowing to enter the `Name` and the`Surname`. There's also a `Button` associated with method `AddPerson`:

```
public void AddPerson(View view)
{
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra("name",editText1.getText().toString());
    data.putExtra("surname",editText2.getText().toString());
    setResult(RESULT_OK,data);
    finish();
}
```

Then, again, in `MainActivity` there is:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        personListAdapter.AddElem(data.getStringExtra("name"), data.getStringExtra("surname"));
    }
```

`PersonListAdapter` is my adapter extended from `BaseAdapter`. Before I'll show the code for it, there are several important things. `Person` is a simple class allowing to save data: `Name` and `Surname`. I have also created custom layout named `list_element_layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameAndSurname"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Ok, and we've got the code for custom adapter:

```
public class PersonListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<Person> personList =new ArrayList<>();
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater; //do tworzenia klasy z XML'a

    public PersonListAdapter(LayoutInflater inflater)
    {
        this.layoutInflater=inflater;
    }

    public void AddElem(String name, String surname)
    {
        personList.add(new Person(name, surname));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return personList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return personList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_element_layout,parent,false); //zapytac o to false
            Person person = personList.get(position);
            TextView nameAndSurname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameAndSurname);
            String textToWrite=person.getName()+" "+person.getSurname();
                nameAndSurname.setText(textToWrite);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In `MainActivity` in `OnCreate` I've added:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        ListView personListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        personListAdapter=new PersonListAdapter(LayoutInflater.from(this));
        personListView.setAdapter(personListAdapter);
    }
```

**Now, the thing is:** after I enter a pair: `Name`, `Surname` in my second activity, I click a button to sent the data back to `MainActivity`, and then I'm using my adapter to update my `ListView`.

**I don't know why, but it doesn't work for the first time (first item that I want to add to the list), and by 'doesn't work' I mean, there's no error, but it goes back to MainActivity and nothing is added to ListView**

**But every next consecutive time it works fine!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing why it didn't work is quite simple. It's because of `Coordinate Layout`. As I'm new with `Android` I didn't know that there are some issues with it while applying `ListView` to applications with API lower than 21. I managed to add it in `XML` file for the `MainActivity` somehow and it works for me, but if I was to make something more serious, I would have to consider tutorials concerning the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.  Try this:

```
public void AddElem(String name, String surname)
{
    personList.add(new Person(name, surname));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Any time you modify the `personList` array list, you need to invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: That's actually not true. It works great as it is, I've explained it in my answer.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved your problem but be advised you still must invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` anytime you change the List used in your custom `BaseAdapter`.  Your code is probably working by some strange timing fluke.  Or you happen to be invoking it external to the `BaseAdapter`. Either way it is still required to do. You may not see the problem, but it's lurking there and can cause later issues depending on how you use the adapter.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution to this post, I appreciate this:) I understand your advice and I must admit it makes sense. At first, I tought that by using `personListAdapter.AddElem(...)` , which causes `List<Person>` defined in my custom adapter class to change, it happens automatically. I mean, I change the content of a list which is used to set all those ID's etc. in overridden methods and it invokes `getView()` method of the adapter. But apparently it doesn't right?:)

Comment: Correct.  The `ListView` the adapter is attached to has no idea that the data has changed.  Invoking `notifyDataSetChanged()` lets it know that the data has changed and UI updates must commence.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_element_layout,parent,false);
    }
    Person person = personList.get(position);
    TextView nameAndSurname = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameAndSurname);
    String textToWrite=person.getName()+" "+person.getSurname();
            nameAndSurname.setText(textToWrite);
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.. Still the same result.